# post from php to my fan page facebook with facebook sdk 5 api 2.4

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I read dozens of articles, the guidelines, I read everything but I do not understand anything. I'm going crazy. Are three days that I'm trying to post on my facebook fan page through the last 4 API 2.4 SDK.
1. I created the app on facebook but the permissions are almost impossible to enforce
2. I have created the appropriate PHP code with the various authentication codes
the result is always the same: NOTHING
Then the questions:
1. What do you need the app to publish on my fan page?
2. What permissions are needed?
3. If I do not have screenshots to be indicated in the permit to push them through whatever I do (I do the screen shot of the source code?).
4. as you get the access token to the fan page?
A desperate help.

```
    $APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //app id
    $APP_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //app secret    
    $TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //access token
    $page_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // facebook page id ottenuto da 
    $message = "Stiamo testando la pubblicazione delle inserzioni anche su Facebook";
    $link = "http://qualcosa";
    $name = "Me";
    /*$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => $APP_ID,
      'app_secret' => $APP_SECRET,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
      ]);

    $linkData = [
      'link' => 'http://qualcosa/altro',
      'message' => $message,
      ];
    var_dump($linkData);        
    $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();       
    var_dump($accessToken);
    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData,$TOKEN);//
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      $msg = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      $msg =  'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    }
    var_dump("MSG: ".$msg);
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    var_dump("Graph: ".$graphNode);
    $msg =  'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
    var_dump($msg);
    $msg="Nulla";

    // I tryed but nothing
```

`try {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($APP_ID, $APP_SECRET);
        $session = new FacebookSession($TOKEN);
        var_dump($session);`

```
    $page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
        'access_token' => $TOKEN,
        'name' => $name,
        'link' => $link,
        'picture' => '',
        'caption' => 'Test da Cip!',
        'message' => $message,
      ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
    {$msg = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();}
    catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
    {$msg =  'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();}
    // return post_id, optional
    var_dump( $page_post );     
    var_dump($msg);
    echo "<br />Finito";
```

Comment: Please add some of the code you have been writing.  Also, the question is hard to understand.  You may be better deleting it and asking a new question, with the code, stating that you are trying to post to your page, that it isn't posting, any error messages you are getting, and that you expect the permissions may be a problem.  If you can link to any websites that you based your code off of, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: 2.4 is not an SDK, it´s the version of the graph api. make sure you understand the difference between an SDK and an API.

Comment: and please start reading the facebook docs, it´s all in there, with example code and the needed permissions. your question is way too broad. you may need to hire a developer if you don´t even know where to look, i´m afraid.

Comment: If you are only using that app yourself, then you don’t need to submit the permissions you want to ask for for review – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#roles

Comment: @luschn I know 2.4 is not a sdk, thank's. It was only to give more details

Comment: @CBroe I don't find anything from faq to resolve my issue. Thank's.

Comment: That was about your statements _“the permissions are almost impossible to enforce”_ and _“I do not have screenshots to be indicated in the permit to push them through”_ – by which I _assume_ you were referring to permission review.

Comment: I don’t see you asking the app user for permissions anywhere in your code.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, but you said you do not need it?

Comment: Those are two totally different issues … You need to submit permissions for review to Facebook, before you can ask “normal” users (that don’t have a role in the app for them) – but if you are only going to use the app yourself, _that_ is not necessary. But _you_ still need to _grant_ those permissions to your app – and that is done by calling the login dialog to ask for them.

Comment: you need to authorize with manage_pages and publish_pages and get a page token in order to post to your page "as page", btw.

Comment: @CBroe I don't know how to this...

Comment: @luschn I have the authorisation in my app in App Center Listed Platforms (WEB) with Configure App Center Permissions

Comment: The configuration for App Center permission applies only when your app is actually accessed _from_ the App Center. And getting listed in App Center also requires review – but if this is an app only for your own personal use, submitting it for review doesn’t make sense, because such apps aren’t eligible for listing in App Center in the first place .

Comment: How to ask for permissions is documented here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#adding And how to do that via the PHP SDK, is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0#examples // If you can’t make heads or tails of the official documentation and the multitude of other resources out there – then you should consider hiring a developer.

Comment: @CBroe thank's. It does not no login, access should be ensured on the token provided by the App. I have read the documentation, but unfortunately the only result that continues to give me back despite evidence made is that I have permission to publish.

Comment: The only token that can be provided “automatically” by an app is the app access token, but you need a page access token to publish “as” a page. How that can be acquired, is also described in the login section of the documentation.

Comment: @CBroe Thank's I try and try again and try again and we do not succeed, and then I come back to ask. Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts I have solved the problem. In graph explorer serves select the App, then the page on publish, assign publishing rights and withdraw the access token created. In the bottom of the page then you can extend the time validity of the token and you will have to use the latter.